# Error converting data type nvarchar to int asp.net c# when executing a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i am a newbie to c#. I have the below code for editing a gridview which puts parameters into a stored procedure but i get the above error when running it. I have tried parsing the parameters with no joy. Any ideas where i am going wrong?

```
protected void PipelineSelection_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = PipelineSelection.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int CustID = Convert.ToChar(PipelineSelection.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string BlueCollar = (row.FindControl("BlueCollarUpdateTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
        string WhiteCollar = (row.FindControl("WhiteCollarUpdateTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
        string PipelineID = (row.FindControl("PipelineUpdateDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        string IndSubSector = (row.FindControl("SectorUpdateDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        string PublicSectorID = (row.FindControl("PublicUpdateDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        string Branches = (row.FindControl("BranchesUpdateBox") as TextBox).Text;
        string Depts = (row.FindControl("DeptsUpdateTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
        string OrderMethodID = (row.FindControl("OrderMethodUpdateDropDown") as DropDownList).SelectedValue;
        string DelRequirements = (row.FindControl("DelUpdateTextBox") as TextBox).Text;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRMConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectCustomerDetails"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", CustID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BlueCollar", Int32.Parse(BlueCollar));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WhiteCollar", Int32.Parse(WhiteCollar));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PipelineID", Int32.Parse(PipelineID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IndSubSectorID", Int32.Parse(IndSubSector));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PublicSectorID", Int32.Parse(PublicSectorID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branches", Int32.Parse(Branches));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Depts", Int32.Parse(Depts));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderMethodID", Int32.Parse(OrderMethodID));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelRequirements", DelRequirements);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "UpPipe");
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        PipelineSelection.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindPipeline();
    }
```

Stored Procedure Below

```
if @Action = 'UpPipe'
Begin

Update CustomerDetails set
NoOfEmployeesBlueCollar = convert(int, @BlueCollar),
NoOfEmployeesWhiteCollar = convert(int, @WhiteCollar),
PipelineID = convert(int, @PipelineID),
IndSubSectorID = convert(int, @IndSubSectorID),
PublicPrivateSectorID = convert(int, @PublicSectorID),
NoOfBranches = convert(int, @Branches),
NoOfDepartments = convert(int, @Depts),
OrderMethodID = convert(int, @OrderMethodID),
DeliveryRequirements = @DelRequirements
where CustID = @CustID

End
```

Comment: post the procedure code body (at least the parameters definition)

Comment: You are also defining all of your variables as strings.  Are all of your non *ID variables, e.g. `BlueCollar`, `WhiteCollar` actual strings?  If so, C# will not be able to convert to an Int.  If all of those variables are truly Ints, then they should be defined as such.

Comment: How would i define them as ints i have tried a load of various combinations that haven't worked